# How to hide a base TypeScript type with an imported type

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, import, intellisense

I am importing the following type with TypeScript 1.8:

```
import { Option } from "react-select-props";
```

However when I try to create an object of type Option, Intellisense thinks it corresponds to the following type from the core library:

```
declare var Option: {new(text?: string, value?: string, defaultSelected?: boolean, selected?: boolean): HTMLOptionElement; };
```

It compiles with the correct type from `react-select-props` however. Am I missing something? How to hide this base type with the imported type and make sure Intellisense reflects this? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and TypeScript Tools 2.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename it:

```
import { Option as ReactPropsOption } from "react-select-props";

let options: ReactPropsOption = {};
```

Comment: Thanks. So no way to shadow the core type? If it compiles and run fine, isn't it a bug in Intellisense then?

Comment: The Intellisense should pick up on all available options for what you're writing. In this case it should show you both `Option`s and narrow it down as you type more. If it doesn't give you the right `Option` then it's not working properly.